# styled components breaks in production only

Tags: javascript, webpack, styled-components

Unfortunately, I can't provide an exact reproduction as my project is huge and I don't know why it breaks.

When building my project and then running it I get

```
0.4fce7d89.chunk.js:10807 Uncaught Error: An error occurred. See https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/packages/styled-components/src/utils/errors.md#1 for more information. Additional arguments: undefined
    at throwStyledComponentsError (0.4fce7d89.chunk.js:10807)
    at constructWithOptions (0.4fce7d89.chunk.js:10986)
    at styled (0.4fce7d89.chunk.js:11586)
    at Object.adf196256915bb4884ae (1.6cb64bdf.chunk.js:21896)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~main.bf917169.js:85)
    at Object.ee92f1fa8d9ef78bb0dc (1.6cb64bdf.chunk.js:27069)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~main.bf917169.js:85)
    at Module.9b1e837f9fa2db581602 (1.6cb64bdf.chunk.js:6160)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime~main.bf917169.js:85)
    at Object.1 (1.6cb64bdf.chunk.js:23)
```

The relevant chunk here is

```
var ListItem = Object(styled_components_browser_esm["default"])(components["h" /* Card */]).withConfig({
  displayName: "ArticleView__ListItem",
  componentId: "sc-1k7vsbl-4"
})(["display:flex;align-items:center;box-shadow:none;background-color:", ";"], Object(app_helpers["b" /* get */])('colors', 'white'));
```

which looks like this:

```
const ListItem = styled(Card)`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: ${p => p.theme.colors.white};
`;
```

Card is just a div with a border radius, that we used before the bug occured.

besides that I checked on many versions, reset `node_modules + yarn.lock`

I don't know how I could possibly debug this here as the error happens only when the project was built by webpack. The project does not have server side rendering.

Comment: Can you build the project locally with prod setting for webpack?

Comment: @Clarity yes, that´s what I do, the error persists.

Comment: I think the code for `ArticleView__ListItem` would be helpful

Comment: @Clarity updated my question

Comment: Shouldn't the color from theme be passed via a function, like `background-color: ${p => p.theme.colors.white};`?

Comment: It seems to have been an issue with some circular dependencies but I still couldn't figure out exactly where the issue is and why it only happens in production

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this same issue as well! It was mainly happening on production build, and I was unable to reproduce the bug locally!! I found no solution after several hours googling. At the end, I was running the production build locally and discovered I had circular dependent styled component on my split(lazy-load) pages and when one page was loading it didn’t have reference to the exported styled component defined on another page. It works locally because we have webpack running.
**So the best practice is to move the styled components to a separate un-split file**. Try not to export a styled component from a split page that needed reference on another page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but I encountered exactly the same error couple of days ago, and I managed to resolve it. The culprit might be your own custom component (the one that you created earlier) that being called (by the 'styled' method) -- in this case is your **Card** component within the **ListItem**.

So the workaround is actually pretty simple. You only have to change the way you write the 'styled' method. So instead of doing this:

```
const ListItem = styled(Card)`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: ${p => p.theme.colors.white};
`;
```

You should write it as follows:

```
const ListItem = styled(props => <Card {...props} />)`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: ${p => p.theme.colors.white};
`;
```

Notice this line:
`styled(props => <Card {...props} />)`

===================

And now you can try to change all other component's syntax that's calling out your other own custom components -- build it, and see if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, I found that the error was circular dependencies since I import like `import {a,b,c} from 'components'`. Your workaround works but has a significant impact on performance I used `transform-imports` instead to make all my imports implicit